# Bypass company gateway authentication from curl

Tags: gateway

I am working for a company. When I access the web application on AWS from the browser, the gateway redirects to the authentication page (work with a proxy), after the authentication I can access the web application from the browser. The problem is that when I am using curl to call the api, the gateway is still redirecting my request to the authentication page. How to pass this authentication layer?

[image]

```
curl -X GET api-url.com
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
< Location: https://company-internet-gateway.com:1234/php/uid.php...
< Content-Length: 0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
```

Comment: How does the authentication work? Is it the part of the application (like OAuth) or a part of the outgoing proxy/firewall (like a welcome page on public hotspots)?

Comment: @30thh It is a proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I added https_proxy with the proxy server then curl worked now.

```
export https_proxy=http://proxy_server:port
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand both requests are not dependent. The authentication server adds you MAC and/or IP address to a white list of the company firewall. Then you can access any other server without authentication.

I would try to replay the authentication requests using curl. Do it in browser, intercept requests using F12 tooling and generate curl commands out of it.